# How to click a button on Chrome to paste a value into an input box?

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I'm trying to import a csv into a webpage in Chrome. From reading similar questions, I'm fairly sure it can be done.

I open the webpage by using

```
Sub import_test()
Dim Website As String
Dim exepath As String
Dim i As Integer
exepath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    Website = ("https://website.com")
    Shell (exepath & " -new-tab " & Website)
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@class='btn-medium btn-alt form-file-btn' and text()='Browse...']").Click
End Sub
```

I tried to then click a button called Browse; the html for that part is:

```
<span class="l-inline-col" style="width: 110px;">
      <a class="btn-medium btn-alt form-file-btn">
        Browse… <input type="file" name="import_file" id="import_file_1" accept=".csv, text/csv">
      </a>
    </span>
```

That's not working. Once this is sorted, I want to paste a file path into the box it brings up, and then click another button called import.

Is all this possible? Or maybe just parts of it?

Comment: Hi @Duane, could you add the other questions you are refering to?

Comment: @Nathan, what do you mean by the other questions? What I'm trying to do after the button has been clicked?

Comment: What is that "driver" which should be an object? The code up to the last line will work, I think...

Comment: I'm not sure, I've basically re-worked some code I reworked from a similar question. Do I need to define the driver as an object then?

Comment: @Duane , what I mean is, could you link the questions you're using so far that you've mentioned in your answer? This would make the question more complete, easier to answer and more useful to others struggling with the same problem

Comment: @Duane: I am afraid that Chrome cannot be automated like Internet Explorer does. There is a VBA Wrapper (selenium basic, if I remember well) which can help you. There also are API able to let you connect to interned browser independent. Also, I think is good to look for XMLHTTP libraries...

Comment: Thanks, @FaneDuru, making a bit of progress with Selenium now.